# Python based alternatives to Node-RED for building an IoT infrastructure

Tags: iot, dataflow

I can only write Python code, and I want to build a IoT infrastructure. Read some sensors (data is received via MQTT influxDB line protocol), follow some simple rule-based logic, send out some API-POST requests etc.. Writing up a big Python script is not an option in my case, because it should be easily modifiable by others without going through a large script.

With Node-RED, functions look like they have to be written in JS. What good alternatives are there, and what are their pros and cons for my application?

Edit:

Specific requirements:

- Inputs should be able to retrieve data via API-GET requests, MQTT brokers
- Processors should be able to be scripted in Python, it would be terrific if there was a way to make python functions available as blocks to other users without actually exposing the underlying python code.
- Outputs would be API-POST requests
- Should be free of charge, an absolute limit would be around EUR 500. Usecase is an academic environment, in case that changes anything
- Should run on Windows
- No performance requirements, it will be a small application and there are lots of resources available

Answer (score 1):

If You want to build IoT on Python - Home Assistant seams to be a good direction ...
It's based on Python and has proper tooling ie:

https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/python_script/